# Reduction of $\frac a{b +1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Can we convert $\frac a{b+1}$ into a fraction having only $b$ as a denominator? What are the steps in doing so?

Comment: Is $\frac{ab\div{(b+1)}}{b}$ acceptable? If not, what is acceptable?

Answer (score 3):

You want
$$\frac{a}{b + 1} = \frac{x}{b}$$
for some $x$, so solve this equation for $x$.  You get $x = \frac{ab}{b + 1}$ so
$$\frac{a}{b + 1} = \frac{\left(\frac{ab}{b + 1}\right)}{b}.$$
Note that if you require your fractions to be one integer divided by another integer then you may be out of luck because $\frac{ab}{b + 1}$ isn't always an integer.

Comment: integers aren't a restriction

Comment: Good, then this should answer your question :)

Answer (score 3):

In general, no, consider $\frac{2}{2+1}=\frac{2}{3}$. We cannot make a fraction of the form $\frac{n}{2}$ with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\frac{n}{2}=\frac{2}{3}$. If we allow fractions in the numerator, then $n=\frac{ba}{b+1}$ will work.

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma** $ $ If $\ q = \dfrac{a}{b\!+\!1}\,$ can also be written with denominator $\,b,\,$ i.e.  $\,q = \dfrac{n}b,\,$ then $\,q\,$ is an integer.

**Proof** $\ $ Since $\,(b\!+\!1)q\,$ and $\,bq\,$ are integers then so too is their difference $\,(b\!+\!1)q-bq\, =\, q.\ \ $

**Remark** $ $ Generally, a fraction can be written with coprime denominators iff it is an integer.

**Proof** $\ $ If $\, q = a/b = c/d\,$ for coprime $\,b,d\,$ then $\, \color{#c00}{jb\!+\!kd = 1}\,$ for $\,j,k\in\Bbb Z,\,$ by Bezout, so

$$ bq,dq\in\Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\, j(bq)+k(dq) = (\color{#c00}{jb\!+\!kd})q = q\in \Bbb Z\qquad\qquad\qquad$$

This is a denominator form of this group theoretic theorem: if $\,g^a = 1 = g^b\,$ for coprime $\,a,b\,$ then $\,g = 1,\,$ since the order of $\,g\,$ divides the coprime $\,a,b\,$ so it can only be $1.\,$ The least denominator of a fraction is simply its order in $\,\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z,\,$ so the above is a special case of this result. See also various posts on [denominator ideals and order ideals.](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:math.stackexchange.com+%28dubuque+OR+%22math+gems%22+OR+%22key+ideas%22%29+%28%22denominator+ideal%22+OR+%22order+ideal%22%29)

Comment: A nice application is [proving](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1165413/242) $\displaystyle\ \dfrac{\gcd(n,m)}n{n\choose m}\in \Bbb Z\ \ $