# How can we prove that a binomial coefficient $n\choose m$is divisible by the ratio of $n$ and $\gcd(n,m)$?

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients, divisibility

Prove that for every $n\geq m \geq1$ natural numbers, the following number is an integer:

$${\gcd(n,m)\over n}\cdot{n\choose m}$$

Where $\gcd$ is the greatest common divisor.

I tried to make it simpler by cancelling the $n$ from the left side, and making it $(n-1)!$ on the right: $\gcd(n, m) \cdot \frac{(n-1)!}{m!(n-m)!}$, but can't really go further.

This was problem B-2 on the [2000 Putnam exam](http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2000.pdf).

Comment: Try to use this:
"Bézout's identity (also called Bézout's lemma) is a theorem in the elementary theory of numbers: let a and b be nonzero integers and let d be their greatest common divisor. Then there exist integers x and y such that ax+by=d"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity

Comment: I tried considering group actions but it didn't pan out. In particular, $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ acts on $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ which induces an action on $\binom{n}{m}$ (the collection of $m$-subsets of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$). If the subgroup $\langle\bar{m}\rangle$ acts freely on $\binom{n}{m}$ then the claim would follow from orbit-stabilizer. Unfortunately the action needn't be free - the smallest counterexample is $m=2$, $n=4$.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Write $nx+my=\gcd(n,m)$, with $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$

Then:

$$\frac{\gcd(n,m)}{n}\binom{n}{m}=\frac{nx+my}{n}\binom{n}{m}=x\binom{n}{m}+y\,\frac{m}{n}\binom{n}{m}=x\binom{n}{m}+y\binom{n-1}{m-1}\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: Wow, I am really impressed! Very nice proof.

Comment: Next question: What's the combinatorial interpretation of the expression that is simplified here? ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 9):

Here is a *conceptual* way to *discover* it. Below we show that it is a special case of the well-known $\rm\color{#0af}{Lemma}$ below that if a fraction $q\,$ can be written with denominators $\,\color{#0a0}n\,$ and $\,\color{#0a0}m,\,$ then it can also be written with denominator being their $\,\color{#0a0}{{\rm gcd} = (n,m)}.\,$ This makes the proof obvious, viz.

$$\begin{align} \color{#0a0}nQ,\ \color{#0a0}mQ\in\Bbb Z\,\ &\Rightarrow\, \color{#0a0}{(n,m)}Q \in\Bbb Z,\  \text{ so for  }\ \color{#c00}Q = \frac{1}{n}{n\choose m}\\
n\color{#c00}Q = {n\choose m},\,\ m\color{#c00}Q= {n\!-\!1\choose m\!-\!1}\in\Bbb Z\,\ &\Rightarrow\ (n,m)\color{#c00}Q = \dfrac{(n,m)}n{{{n\choose m}}}\in \Bbb Z.\ \ \ \small\bf QED\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

---

$\rm\color{#0af}{Lemma}\ $ If a fraction $\,q = c/d\,$ can be written with denominators $\,n\,$ and $\,m,\,$ then it can also be written with denominator being their gcd $ =(n,m)$.

**Proof** $\ $  We give a *four* proofs of this basic result since doing so proves instructive (the proof in the other answer is essentially $(3)$ below, but here we highlight the innate conceptual structure).

$(1)\ $ [Recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/825667/show-that-if-fd-fd-and-the-pairs-f-d-and-f-d-are-coprime-then-f/825871#825871) that a fraction can be written with denominator $\,n\,$ iff its least denominator $\,d\mid n.\,$ Hence $\,m,n\,$ are denoms $\!\iff\! d\mid m,n\!\iff\! d\mid (m,n)\!\iff\! (m,n)\,$ is a denom, by [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/198801/242).

$(2)\ \ \dfrac{mc}d,\dfrac{nc}d\in\Bbb Z\iff d\mid mc,nc\iff d\mid (mc,nc)=(m,n)c\iff\! \dfrac{(m,n)c}d\in\Bbb Z$

$(3)\ \ \dfrac{mc}d, \dfrac{nc}d\in\Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow  \dfrac{jmc}d,\, \dfrac{knc}d\in\Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\,\dfrac{(jm\!+\!kn)c}d\,\overset{\large \color{#c00}{\exists\, j,k}_{\phantom{1^{1^{1}}\!\!\!\!\!}}} = \dfrac{(m,n)c}d\in\Bbb Z\ $ by $\rm\color{#c00}{Bezout}$

$(4)\ \ \,\bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{q = \dfrac{C}{D} = \dfrac{c}d\,\Rightarrow\, q= \dfrac{(C,c)}{(D,d)}}\,\ $ by $\ d(C,c) = (dC,dc) = (cD,dc) = c(D,d)$

$(4)\,$ can be viewed as  special case of an [extension of gcd to rationals.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/151431/242). $(3)$ is a special case of $(2)$ arising by recplacing gcds by their linear Bezout rep (it is less general because [Bezout fails](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/673192/242) in many common gcd domains, e.g. polynomial UFDs like $\,\Bbb Z[x],$ and $\,\Bbb Q[x,y])$.

---

**Remark** $ $ The $\rm\color{#90f}{Lemma}$ is a denominator form of this ubiquitous [group theory theorem:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/11636/242)

$\qquad$ If $\,q^m\! = 1 = q^n\,$ then $\,q^{(m,n)}=1,\ $ by $\ {\rm ord}(q)\mid m,n\Rightarrow {\rm ord}(q)\mid (m,n)$

The least denominator of a fraction is its *order* in $\,\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z,\,$ so the Lemma is a special case of this result. For  more on this viewpoint (denominator and order ideals) see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4421745/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3295370/242).

Comment: See also [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1158286/242)

Comment: Nice, that's a bit harder (in my opinion) to come up with, but very elegant.

Comment: @user2520938 See the edit which emphasizes the innate conceptual viewpoint.

Comment: It's rather sad that answers that strive to  emphasize *conceptual* viewpoints often get downvoted - whereas those that don't often get upvoted. This of course is one of the great challenges of mathematical pedagogy - how to coax students to comprehend something a bit more general when it seems easier to simply  go with something less general (e.g. proofs pulled out of a hat like magic).

Comment: Applying this lemma to $q=\frac{1}{n}\binom{n}{m}$ is just as much pulled out of a hand as the approaches of the other answers. At the end there is not much conceptually deep/interesting going on here, it is just in one way or another playing around with fundamental properties of the gcd.

Comment: @user2520938 The point is that order-theoretic viewpoint emphasized above is *ubiquitous*, and viewing it this was makes the proof much more intuitive (it is not simply unmotivated "playing around").