# Easy proof: $\binom{n}{k}$ is divisible by $n$ for $\gcd(n,k)=1$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, divisibility, binomial-theorem

Can someone give me an easy (two or three line) proof for the fact that $\dbinom{n}{k}$ is divisible by $n$ for $k\not=0, n$ and $\gcd(n,k)=1.$
Here $\dbinom{n}{k}$ denotes usual binomial coefficients.

Comment: A combinatorial proof would be cool!

Comment: There is a combinatorial proof that  $k \dbinom{n}{k}=n \dbinom{n-1}{k-1} $, but you will not avoid an arithmetic argument since we are using a gcd.

Comment: Some related older posts: [The divisibility of a particular case of $\binom{x}{y}$ (when $(x,y) = 1$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2070494) and [${\gcd(n,m)\over n}{n\choose m}$ is an integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1165229)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$k>0$, thus $\dbinom{n}{k}=\frac n k\dbinom{n-1}{k-1} $ Thus if $\gcd(n,k)=1$, n divides $\frac n k\dbinom{n-1}{k-1} $

**Bonus :** Combinatorial proof that $\dbinom{n}{k}=\frac n k\dbinom{n-1}{k-1} $ :

If you want to choose a team of k people amongst n with one team leader, you can :

- choose a leader first (n possibilities) then choose the remaining k-1 members amongst the n-1 remaining possiblities
- choose the k people first, then choose a leader amongst the k people team.

Thus $k\dbinom{n}{k}=n \dbinom{n-1}{k-1}$

Comment: Suppose $\gcd(n,k)=d.$ Is it true that$\dbinom{n}{k}$ is divisible by $\dfrac{n}{d}$ ?

Comment: yes, using the same argument and basic divisibility formulae

Answer (score 1):

The slightly more general result that $\frac{n}{\gcd (n,k)}$ divides $\binom{n}{k}$ (with $n\geq 1$ and $1\leq k \leq n$) can be proven quite easily using a couple results from group theory, as well as the identity $$k\binom{n}{k}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$
Consider the (additive) group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ of integers modulo $n$. The element $\bar{1}_n$ has order $n$, and for $k\in \lbrace 1,...,n \rbrace$, we have that $\binom{n}{k}(k{\bar 1}_{n})=\binom{n}{k}k{\bar 1}_{n}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}n{\bar 1}_{n}\underset{n \textrm{ divides } \binom{n-1}{k-1}n}{=} {\bar 0}_{n}$. Thus $\binom{n}{k}$ is divisible by the order of $k{\bar 1}_{n}$, which is equal to $\frac{n}{\gcd (n,k)}$. QED

Comment: But how do you define $n/k$ mod $n$?

Comment: You don't have to define $n/k$ mod $n$ for this proof to be valid. At one point I multiplied an element of $\mathbb Z /n \mathbb Z$ not by $n/k$ but by $\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}$, which is an integer, so everything is well-defined.

That being said, you're bringing up a good point since that step isn't needed for the proof. I'll edit my comment to clear up the confusion, thanks for the reply.