# If $a$ is rational and $18a$ and $25a$ integers then so is $a$. Same for any coprime multipliers. Denominators closed under gcd.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers, rational-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

Let $a\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $18a$ and $25a$ are integers, then we wish to prove that $a$ must be an integer itself. What that means is that $a=\frac{p}{1}$ where $p \in \mathbb{Z}$. What we do know is that we can express the $\gcd(18,25)$ as: 
$$ \gcd(18,25)=18x +25y$$ Now if $x=y=a$, we are done, since:
$$ \gcd(18,25)=18a +25a=43a$$ as the $\gcd$ is always an integer and so is 43, so $a$ is also an integer.

But, how would I generalise this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you know is that there are *some* $x$ and $y$ with that property, but that doesn't imply that you can take $x=y=a$.

Note that $\gcd(18,25)=1$. Therefore, there are integers $x$ and $y$ such that $18x+25y=1$. But then $a=18xa+25ya\in\mathbb Z$, since $18a,25a,x,y\in\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 3):

You can also prove this by contradiction:

Assume $a=\frac{m}{n}$, where $m,n$ are coprime and $n\gt1$. Then, if $18a=k_1\in\mathbb{Z}$, by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic $$n=2^b3^c.$$ However, assuming $$25a=k_2\in\mathbb{Z},$$ implies $n=5$ or $n=25$, which is obviously a contradiction.

Comment: Then n must be 1.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to look at this:  $18a$ and $25a$ are integers.  Therefore, so is $25a-18a = 7a$.

Therefore so is $18a-2(7a) = 4a.$

Therefore so is $7a-4a = 3a.$

Therefore so is $4a-3a = a.$

Comment: Oh... wow... this is nice too

Answer (score 3):

*Conceptually* $\, \dfrac{m}{18} \!=\! a \!=\! \dfrac{n}{25}\,$ [so](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/825871/242) its least denominator divides *coprimes* $18,25$ so is $1,\,$ so $\,a\in\Bbb Z$

**Remark** $\ $ This is an additive analog of this better-known (multiplicative) group result

$$ a^{\large 18} = 1 = a^{\large 25}\,\Rightarrow\, {\rm ord}(a)\mid 18,25\,\Rightarrow\, {\rm ord}(a)=1\,\Rightarrow\, a = 1\qquad$$

Generally if a rational can be written with denominators $\,a\,$ and $\,b\,$ then it can be written with denominator $\,\gcd(a,b).\,$ See
also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4421745/242) and see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1165413/242)  for four proofs and elaboration.

For further discussion see  [denominator ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a242%20%22denominator%20ideals%22) and [order ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a242%20%22order%20ideals%22) and [unique fractionization](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a242%20%22unique%20fractionization%22).