# is $\binom{m}{n}$ an integer if $m \geq n$ are positive integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisibility

Question B-2 of the [2000 Putnam Exam](http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2000.pdf) was answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1165229/how-can-we-prove-that-a-binomial-coefficient-n-choose-mis-divisible-by-the-rat). in all the answers everyone assumes that $\binom{m}{n}$ is an integer for $m \geq n \geq 1$ integers, but gives no further explanation as to why.

When I tried to prove it myself, I was met with complicated expressions that prevented me from continuing.
My question is: what is the simple way to prove that $\binom{m}{n}$ is an integer for $m \geq n$ positive integers?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11601/proof-that-a-combination-is-an-integer

Answer (score 1):

Newton's symbol is used to compute the number of ways to choose n elements from a set with m elements. It is assumed that the order of the chosen elements is irrelevant, that is, {a, b} = {b, a}. That is regarded as the same choice.

So you look at m elements and take n of them. How many ways are there to do that if order is to be accounted for? You have m options for the first, (m-1) options for the second etc, all the way up to the last element: (m-(n-1)) options. Hence there are $\frac{m!}{(m-n)!}$ choices.

But remember, one ought to discard all the unnecessary permutations! Since n elements have been chosen, one should divide the outcome by the number of the possible permutations of the output-set, that is, divide by n!.

The number of choices has to be an integer, which completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to see it is to use the "combinatorial" definition of $\binom mn$.

The binomial coefficient $\binom mn$ may be defined in two ways. One way is algebraic:
$$\binom mn=\frac{m!}{n!(m-n)!}.$$
This lets you manipulate binomial coefficients, and is quite useful (for example) in solving the Putnam problem. Another way, which is usually how $\binom mn$ is defined (as far as I can recall), is as "the number of ways to choose $n$ objects from a set of $m$ distinct objects, with the order of the objects chosen being irrelevant." For example, $\binom 32=3$, as there are three ways to choose two objects from a set of $3$: if the set is $\{A,B,C\}$, then you could choose $A$ and $B$, or $A$ and $C$, or $B$ and $C$. Using this definition, it's obvious that $\binom mn$ should be an integer -- it counts the number of ways to do something.

The utility of binomial coefficients is that these definitions are *equivalent*. In other words, one can show that the number of ways to choose $n$ objects from a set of $m$ distinct objects, without caring about the order in which the objects are chosen, is exactly
$$\frac{m!}{n!(m-n)!}.$$
This allows one to use either the combinatorial or algebraic definition at any point, and leads to a very clean solution of the Putnam problem (among many other applications). A proof is as follows.

1. Consider first the problem of choosing the $n$ objects and caring about the order. Then, there are $m$ ways to choose the first object, $m-1$ ways to choose the second (since you can choose any object of the $m$ besides the object which was chosen as the first one), all the way through $m-n+1$ ways to choose the last object. So, the number of ways to do this is
   $$m(m-1)(m-2)\cdots(m-n+1)=\frac{m!}{(m-n)!}.$$
2. Now, let $A$ be the number of ways to do this choosing without caring about order. The number of ways to do this choosing with caring about order is $A\cdot n!$: first choose the elements, then order them in any way. This tells us that
   $$A\cdot n!=\frac{m!}{(m-n)!},$$
   and so $A=\frac{m!}{n!(m-n)!}$, as desired.